# Postgres regex to uppercase

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

How can I use regex in Postgres to replace a capture with an upper case version of itself.

```
regexp_replace(pf.description, '^(.)(.*)$', '\U\1\E\2', 'gi') as description
```

is giving me the string back with the literal values `\U` and `\E`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing regex matched text with uppercase version in Postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698760/replacing-regex-matched-text-with-uppercase-version-in-postgresql)

Comment: Are you using an outdated version of Postgres or why do you escape literal characters?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter What literal characters have I escaped?

Comment: `\U` and `\E`, or do you need that literally?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter `\U` and `\L` are how I change case using regex. I am just trying to make the first letter of the string upper case.

Comment: Neither `\U` nor `\E` nor `\L` have any special meaning in Postgres regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in regex functionality in Postgres to convert to upper / lower case (that I'd know of).

I would use [`left()` and `right()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) instead:

```
SELECT upper(left('test_string', 1))
    || lower(right('test_string', -1));
```

Result:

```
Test_string
```

[Postgres regular expression functionality in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks much.