# Postgres SQL to convert first letter after Mc to upper case

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data in Postgres SQL, something like this

```
Name
Peter C Mcdonald
Mccarthy
```

I am trying to convert first letter after Mc to uppercase , something as below

```
Name
Peter C McDonald
McCarthy
```

I am using initcap function as below, but its not working as expected

```
Select initcap(name) from table
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Does Mc  case sensetive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing regex matched text with uppercase version in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698760/replacing-regex-matched-text-with-uppercase-version-in-postgresql)

Comment: No, the above seems different to what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select case when name like '%Mc%' then concat(split_part(name,'Mc',1),'Mc',initcap(split_part(name,'Mc',2))) else name end from table
```

Use above query it will give desired results.

Comment: Thanks , this works. But is there any other way to identify the records instead of like function

Comment: May be there. But I do not know.

Comment: I will update answer if I found.